# grouping the data based on one property antd table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to group the data currently its working for three, if i remove any one gender then i wont be able to get it the same design,

Basically if the state_name is same then it should be grouped into same even there is only one gender or more than one as shown below

[image: sample design]

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/grouped-data-muptr)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, basically having a variable outside, when the sameKey repeats not setting the count making rowSpan as 0 so it will be hidden.

Logic

```
  let sameKey;
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "District",
      dataIndex: "state_name",
      key: "state_name",
      render: (value, row, index) => {
        const obj = {
          children: value,
          props: {}
        };
        if (!(sameKey !== value)) {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
          return obj;
        }
        const count = data.filter(item => item.state_name === value).length;
        sameKey = value;
        obj.props.rowSpan = count;
        return obj;
      }
    },
```

See the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/grouped-data-muptr)